# Specify which GPU to run Tensorboard on

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am working on a Linux machine shared by multiple users. This machine has four different GPU devices. I would like to run both my Tensorflow network and my Tensorboard monitoring process on one of the open GPUs. At the moment, the primary GPU (GPU-0) is fully loaded with some other user's process(es):

`+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.46                 Driver Version: 390.46                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 50%   84C    P2   216W / 250W |  11124MiB / 11178MiB |     97%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   33C    P8    17W / 250W |  10845MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   32C    P8    16W / 250W |  10845MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   27C    P8    16W / 250W |  10845MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+`

When I try to run tensorboard with the command:
`tensorboard --logdir=path_to_directory` I get a CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY error. This is obviously due to tensorboard trying to run on fully loaded GPU. Is there a way to run tensorboard on one of the open GPUs?

Comment: You can run tensorboard without any GPU. Just set the Env–VAR „CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=„ to either -1 or left it empty.

Comment: Thank you @Patwie. I set the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environmental variable to -1 using the command:
`export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1`
This enabled tensorboard to run on the CPU.

Comment: There was a [similar thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1155#issuecomment-401943552) in `tensorboard` repo, which says that this issue of tensorboard is fixed on version 1.9 and so this shouldn't be a case with latest stable version of tensorflow. If the error still persists, kindly follow up with this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1155). Thanks!